# I can't get array.filter to work with useState

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I am trying to delete an item from a shopping cart and I am using the filter hook to accomplish this. I have looked at the documentation for this and at the answers here on stack overflow. unfortunately no luck.

this is my code for the entire component. the function is of course "deleteItemFromBasket" and it is being called at the onclick on the delete button:

```
function CheckoutProduct({id, title, price, description, rating, category, image }) {
    const [basket, addToBasket] = useAppContext();

    const deleteItemFromBasket = (id) => {
        addToBasket(basket.filter((task) => task.id !== id));
    };

    return (
    <div>
        {basket.map((element) => {
            if (element === id) {
                return (
                    <div className='grid grid-cols-5 border-b pb-4'>
                         {/* far left */}
                        <Image src={image} height={200} width={200} objectFit='contain' />

                
                    {/* middle */}
                        <div className="col-span-3 mx-5">
                            <p>{title}</p>
                            <p className='text-xs my-2 line-clamp-3'>{description}</p>

                        <button onClick={deleteItemFromBasket} className='button'>delete</button>

                        <h1>items ID in basket: {basket}</h1>
                            <h1>length of array: {basket.length}</h1>
                        </div>

                    {/* right */} 
                        <div>
                            <p>${price}</p>
                        </div>    
                    </div>  
                )
            }
        })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

here is the code of the context provider

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';


const AppContext = createContext();

export function AppWrapper({ children }) {
  var [basket, addToBasket]= useState([]);

 
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={[basket, addToBasket]}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>

  );
}

export function useAppContext() {
  return useContext(AppContext);
}
```

Comment: What does `useAppContext` do?

Comment: if I understand it correctly it allows me to connect to my context api

Comment: Seems like a good guess from the name, but it could do literally anything. Can you show us that code please? If it is connecting to context we'll need to see the context provider as well.

Comment: yes I will edit the post now

Comment: is there anything else that you might need to see?

Answer (score 0):

looks like `basket` is an array of `id`s, not an array of objects. Assuming that is the case, then you need to change your delete function to

```js
const deleteItemFromBasket = (id) => {
  addToBasket(basket.filter((element) => element !== id));
};
```

This is assuming that `addToBasket` is actually just setting the basket, not just additive.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work, I believe all of your assumptions were correct.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got it to work and it took a combination of the two answers so thank you everyone for the help!

notice below that the function "deleteItemFromBasket" is the same as joe's post but it to get it to work I needed to add the function in the onClick like zehan's answer. I don't know why this works so if anyone has an explanation as to why I'll save the answer spot for it! thanks friends

```
import React from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image'
import { useAppContext } from '../state'


function CheckoutProduct({id, title, price, description, rating, category, image }) {
    const [basket, addToBasket] = useAppContext();

    const deleteItemFromBasket = (item) => {

        addToBasket((current) => current.filter((element) => element !== item));
    };


    return (
    <div>
        {basket.map((element) => {
            if (element === id) {
                return (
                    <div className='grid grid-cols-5 border-b pb-4'>
                         {/* far left */}
                        <Image src={image} height={200} width={200} objectFit='contain' />

                
                    {/* middle */}
                        <div className="col-span-3 mx-5">
                            <p>{title}</p>
                            <p className='text-xs my-2 line-clamp-3'>{description}</p>
                        {/* <button onClick={deleteItemFromBasket(element)} >delete item</button> */}
                        <button onClick={ ()=> deleteItemFromBasket(id)} className='button'>delete</button>
                        <h1>items ID in basket: {basket}</h1>
                            <h1>length of array: {basket.length}</h1>
                        </div>

                    {/* right */} 
                        <div>
                            <p>${price}</p>
                        </div>    
                    </div>  
                )
            }
        })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Two things I noticed: the `rating` and `category` props are not being used anywhere within the `CheckoutProduct` component. If you are not using them, you can just remove them. Secondly, you are missing the `key` prop on your `div` within `basket.map()`.